# Get sum of incoming matrices in java

Tags: java, matrix

I am getting a file with lot of matrices.i need to sum it up into 1 matrix.
I parsed the string and stored them in an array
the incoming file content is

```
0.000 0.000 0.000
 0.000 0.000 0.000
 0.000 0.000 1.000

9.0 12.0    -3.0    
12.0    16.0    -4.0    
-3.0    -4.0    1.0

25.0    45.0    -5.0    
45.0    81.0    -9.0    
-5.0    -9.0    1.0

144.0   12.0    -12.0   
12.0    1.0 -1.0    
-12.0   -1.0    1.0

64.0    56.0    -8.0    
56.0    49.0    -7.0    
-8.0    -7.0    1.0

81.0    72.0    -9.0    
72.0    64.0    -8.0    
-9.0    -8.0    1.0

36.0    72.0    -6.0    
72.0    144.0   -12.0   
-6.0    -12.0   1.0

100.0   80.0    -10.0   
80.0    64.0    -8.0    
-10.0   -8.0    1.0 

64.0    40.0    -8.0    
40.0    25.0    -5.0    
-8.0    -5.0    1.0 

196.0   112.0   -14.0   
112.0   64.0    -8.0    
-14.0   -8.0    1.0
```

After summing up i shld get

```
719.000 501.000 -75.000
 501.000 508.000 -62.000
 -75.000 -62.000 10.000
```

as my result.

I tried this. but not getting the desired output.i am able to get all the parsed values in 'A'

```
/*Parsed*/

           double[][] A = new double[keymatrix.length][keymatrix[0].length];
           for (int i = 0; i<keymatrix.length; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j<keymatrix[0].length; j++) {
                   A[i][j] = Double.valueOf(keymatrix[i][j]);
            }
           }
          key = new double[A.length][A[0].length];

           for(int sumi = 0;sumi<A.length;sumi++){
               for(int sumj=0;sumj<A[0].length;sumj++){
                   key[sumi][sumj] += A[sumi][sumj];
               }
           }
        }//end loop and key declared as static double [][] ke

               System.out.println("final");
            for(int diai=0;diai<key.length;diai++){
                for(int diaj=0;diaj<key[0].length;diaj++){
                    System.out.print(key[diai][diaj]+"\t");

                }
                System.out.println("");

            }
```

when i checked my output Key is printing the ke value

output along with iteration

```
.
.
.
incoming matrix
64.0    40.0    -8.0    
40.0    25.0    -5.0    
-8.0    -5.0    1.0 
final
64.0    40.0    -8.0    
40.0    25.0    -5.0    
-8.0    -5.0    1.0
incoming matrix
196.0   112.0   -14.0   
112.0   64.0    -8.0    
-14.0   -8.0    1.0 
final
196.0   112.0   -14.0   
112.0   64.0    -8.0    
-14.0   -8.0    1.0
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Please try  a debugger. Also try writing small unit tests.

Comment: It appears that you are only adding in one matrix.

Comment: but as it is loop..my 1st value will be with in key right.wen 2 nd loop starts my new A get added with prevous A stored in Key na?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code provided you are rebuilding the matrix key inside the loop.

You should build it once before the loop and then add to it. By calling

```
key = new double[A.length][A[0].length];
```

inside the loop you are effectively resetting its value each time.

Also two suggesionts:

1) I don't understand what is the point of Matrix A you seem to have the values you want in keymatrix so why copy over to A then to key?

2) define the size of the matrix once `int rows = keymatrix.length; int cols = keymatrix[0].length`. Then use these values everywhere. It will make the code easier to understand.

If you have a function that returns the next matrix read from input or null if there is no new input you end up with something like this:

```
String[][] keyMatrix = read_matrix(); //reads the first matrix from input 
int rows = keyMatrix.length;
int cols = keyMatrix[0].length;
double[][] sumMatrix= new double[rows][cols];

do {
    for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
          sumMatrix[i][j] +=  Double.valueOf(keyMatrix[i][j]);
       }
    }
} while (null != ( keyMatrix=read_matrix()  ));
```

Comment: but i will not be able to get the dimension outside the loop.

Comment: my keymatrix is string.so after parsing i am converting it to double and tried to sum up all the A matrices .and the final sumup value is in key matrix

Comment: I'm editing the code to explain how to get the dimension inside the loop. And to work without A @NSK

Comment: thx for the explanation @odedsh. ys i will change the code accordingly but i am only able to get the rows and cols after parsing the string.

Comment: The important bit is not to write over the matrix where you keep the sum inside the loop.
This wipes clean the matrix which is why you don't see a sum only the values of the last matrix read.